# How to get facebook friends using playfab?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, photon

i have been trying to access the facebook friendlists of the facebook test users through playfab. am using this code

```
public void FriendLists(){
    GetFriendsListRequest request = new GetFriendsListRequest ();
    request.IncludeFacebookFriends = true;
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetFriendsList (request, GetFriends, FriendListError);
}

void GetFriends(GetFriendsListResult result){
    friends = result.Friends;
    Debug.Log("Friends");
    for(int i=0;i<friends.Count;i++){
        Debug.Log(friends[i].Username);
    }
}
```

I have saved the Facebook app id and secret in playfab/setting/secret keys

All my test users are friends with each other

I have also logged in from the individual accounts to play fab.

but the friendlist still returns a null.

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your test users have granted the permission `user_friends` to your app.

You can check the permission for each test user using their access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/.

Answer (score 0):

We have [a thread in our ticket system](https://community.playfab.com/questions/117/205469418.html), but so others have the info:

Yes, setting IncludeFacebookFriends to true will cause the API to include Facebook friends who have also played the same game (Title ID), if those friends have also linked their Facebook account to their PlayFab account, and the token permissions allow for friend info.

The most common issue we see is a mistake when entering the Facebook App ID and Secret. Can you re-check those, to ensure they match exactly?

Next, check that the players in question have all linked their Facebook accounts. If both of those check out (given that you've already confirmed the token permissions), could you send us the PlayFab sign-in credentials for a user in this state (you can email devrel@playfab.com)?

Answer (score 0):

The PlayFab Friend Manager Module is specifically designed to manage friend features. There are 4 method by which we can get facebook friends using playfab.

1.Add Friend by Email
2. Add Friend by PlayFabID
3. Add Friend by DisplayName
4.Add Friend by Username